# CSS Grid: Border for incomplete rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there a way to have a CSS grid (`display: grid`) that has a 1px border around all items and also fills incomplete rows? The approach of setting the `background-color` seems to not be a viable solution.

My goals would be to have a grid without the grey area in the code snippet where items are missing and the grid lines always extending all the way through the table. This should work for responsive combinations of items per row.

It almost seems like special pseudo classes would be needed for **doesn't have item below** and **doesn't have item to the right** to make this work in responsive layouts because last-of-type has too little information about the grid to use it for styling.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.grid > div {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should apply

- the same `background-color` for grid container and grid items
- right and bottom borders for grid items with negative
  margins (this will be compensated by grid gaps).

Demo:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  background-color: white;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.grid > div {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-right: inherit;
  margin-right: -1px;
  border-bottom: inherit;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```